Physical memory addressing and Hugepage allocation on Linux/GRUB with x86 asymmetrical memory channels
Let’s say you have a modern AMD/Intel x86 machine with 2 DRAM DIMMs, configured as asymmetrical dual channel. One of them is 16GB and the other 48GB.
In this case, I want to forbid general usage of 32GB in the bigger DIMM and mark them as 32 * 1GB Hugepages. This will force the region of Hugepages would be accessed as single-channel, the other is fully dual-channel.
Is it possible to accomplish the above scenario within Linux? If it is, how? AFAIK, the physical addressing of x86 asymmetrical memory channel would have low-address region with cross-configured by channel-width (64-bit) and high-address region sorely on the single-channel.
